# Why Python chokes on this regex?

Tags: python, regex

This looks like a simple regex, no backreferences, no "any" characters, I'd even dare to say it's parseable by a Thomson DFA and all. It even works, but chokes on very simple non-matches.

```
{\s*?
ngx_string\("(?P<name>[a-z0-9_]+)"\)\s*?,\s*?
(?P<where>(([A-Z0-9_]+)\s*\|?)+?)\s*?,\s*?
(?P<bla>[^\n}]+?)\s*?,\s*?
(?P<bla2>[^\n}]+?)\s*?,\s*?
(?P<bla3>[^\n}]+?)\s*?,\s*?
(?P<bla4>[^\n}]+?)\s*?
}

+ re.MULTILINE | re.VERBOSE
```

[runnable gist here](https://gist.github.com/PAStheLoD/5321596ae7068fe9639a)

I'm currently trying this on Python 2.7.8 (but the linked gist fails on py3.4 too; also linux, x86-64, Ubuntu, PCRE statically linked in [at least /proc//maps doesn't show anything interesting).

This parses well:

```
{ ngx_string("daemon"),
  NGX_MAIN_CONF|NGX_DIRECT_CONF|NGX_CONF_FLAG,
  ngx_conf_set_flag_slot,
  0,
  offsetof(ngx_core_conf_t, daemon),
  NULL },
```

And this is where the fun stops:

```
 { ngx_string("off"), NGX_HTTP_REQUEST_BODY_FILE_OFF },
 { ngx_string("on"), NGX_HTTP_REQUEST_BODY_FILE_ON },
```

Also, more data:

by changing the second line to this

```
(?P<where>(([A-Z0-9_]{1,20})\s*\|?){1,6}?)\s{0,10}?,\s{0,10}?
```

, it finally completes in reasonable time, but the exponential blowing up is still there, just bearable:

```
trying      { ngx_string("off"), NGX_HTTP_REQUEST_BODY_FILE
Took 0.033483 s
trying      { ngx_string("off"), NGX_HTTP_REQUEST_BODY_FILE_
Took 0.038528 s
trying      { ngx_string("off"), NGX_HTTP_REQUEST_BODY_FILE_O
Took 0.044108 s
trying      { ngx_string("off"), NGX_HTTP_REQUEST_BODY_FILE_OF
Took 0.053547 s
```

Also, interestingly a JS-based Python regex (emulator?) parser can eat it like it's breakfast for PCRE champs: https://www.debuggex.com/r/S__vSvp8-LGLuCLQ

Oh, and maybe someone should create the pathological-regex tag :|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `(([A-Z0-9_]+)\s*\|?)+?` in your original regex or `(([A-Z0-9_]{1,20})\s*\|?){1,6}?` in your test regex. The `{1,20}` and `{1,6}` only serves to inhibit the exponential backtracking a bit.

Since `\s*` and `\|?` are optional, the regex can expand to the classic example of exponential backtracking `(([A-Z0-9_]+))+?` when the input contains only `[A-Z0-9_]` without spaces or bar `|`, but does not matches the rest of the regex.

For example, matching `(?P<where>(([A-Z0-9_]+)\s*\|?)+?)\s*?,\s*?` against `AAAAAAAAAAAAAA` (`,` is missing) would cause the engine to check all possibility of splitting the string up, each token to be matched at different iterations of the outer repetition:

```
AAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAA A
AAAAAAAAAAAA AA
AAAAAAAAAAAA A A
AAAAAAAAAAA AAA
...
A AAAAAAAAAAAAA
A AAAAAAAAAAAA A
A AAAAAAAAAAA AA
...
A A A A A A A A A A A A A A
```

On a closer look, the rest of your regex also have excessive backtracking problem.

Take `(?P<bla2>[^\n}]+?)\s*?,\s*?` for example. `[^\n}]` can match a space (or a tab, or a number of other space characters), and so can `\s`. This may cause excessive backtracking if your non-matching input contains a long string of spaces. There might also be correctness issue, since `,` can be matched by `[^\n}]` also.

On a side note, Python `re` is an NFA engine without any optimization to mitigate the exponential backtracking problem.

To mitigate the exponential backtracking:

```
{\s*
ngx_string\("(?P<name>[a-z0-9_]+)"\)\s*,\s*
(?P<where>[A-Z0-9_]+(?:\s*\|\s*[A-Z0-9_]+)*)\s*,\s*
(?P<bla>[^\n}]+?)\s*,\s*
(?P<bla2>[^\n}]+?)\s*,\s*
(?P<bla3>[^\n}]+?)\s*,\s*
(?P<bla4>[^\n}]+?)\s*
}
```

The excessive backtracking and correctness problem with `[^\n}]` are still not fixed. The `,` in function call can be wrongly recognized as part of the outer block `{}` if the arguments are not on different lines.

The general solution would require recursive regex, since you can call a function as pass its result as argument, e.g. `offsetof(ngx_core_conf_t, daemon)`, but the recursive regex feature is not available in `re` package. A less general solution would be to match up to some levels of nested parentheses, for example 1 level of nesting:

```
(?P<bla>(?:\([^)]*\)|[^,()])+),\s*
```

And the whole regex is:

```
{\s*?
ngx_string\("(?P<name>[a-z0-9_]+)"\)\s*,\s*
(?P<where>[A-Z0-9_]+(?:\s*\|\s*[A-Z0-9_]+)*)\s*,
(?P<bla>(?:\([^)]*\)|[^,()])+),\s*
(?P<bla2>(?:\([^)]*\)|[^,()])+),\s*
(?P<bla3>(?:\([^)]*\)|[^,()])+),\s*
(?P<bla4>(?:\([^)]*\)|[^,()])+)
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://regex101.com/r/sR8xK2/1)

There are 2 caveats:

- The `<bla*>` capturing groups will contain spaces at the end. The regex will be a bit longer if you want to remove spaces, **and** prevent possible excessive backtracking. You can try adding `\s*` before the `,` back into [this demo here](http://regex101.com/r/sR8xK2/2).
- It assumes that `()` are not part of any string literal.

Comment: Thanks for the details. So it seems that Python has its own Regex engine. Any tips for mitigating the problem at hand?

Answer (score 2):

```
(?P<where>(([A-Z0-9_]+)\s*\|?)+?)
                     ^        ^
```

This is where your regex is exploding.Read http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html .

On every failure it goes back one step to check if there is a match.This is creating an explosion of steps and possibilities for the regex engine.